# adding dashboard state (as described in get started tutorial) failed

Tags: state, dashboard, thingsboard

Hi I am following the get started video tutorial and stuck when I try to add the dashboard state. After filling in the Name and id I press the add button and the state window is closed and the edit modus is cancelled. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? I am using ThingsBoard 2.2.0

Comment: It seems to work on my test environment. But I haven't updated it to 2.2 yet. The steps I took: `0) Login as tenant admin`; `1) Open a dashboard`; `2) Enter dashboard edit mode` (orange button bottom right); `3) Open "manage dashboard states" dialog` (button in the dashboard header-toolbar); `4) Add dashboard state` (plus buttton in state list); `5) Enter "asdf" in Name-Input` (State-Id is filled automatically); `6) Press Add Button to confirm dialog`; `7) Press save button to confirm dialog`; `8) Press save button to save dashboard changes` (orange checkmark button on the bottom right)

Comment: Please open browser debug console and check for errors. Attach errors if present to help you investigate.